# SQL server Store Procedure run slow on first time

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Why this is running slow at first time? What can I do to avoid this?

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMicrosoftXmlFeedData]   
    @PageTemplateIds varchar(500),  
    @PageTemplateLocationIds varchar(500),  
    @ContentTypeIds varchar(500),  
    @PageSourceIds varchar(500),  
    @NumberOfDays int  = 1  
    AS  
      BEGIN  
          select    
           P.pageid  
      , P.maskurl as ArticleURL  
      , C.ContentID  
      , cast(C.ContentXML as xml).value('Content[1]/Headline[1]','varchar(200)') as Headline   
      , cast(C.ContentXML as xml).value('Content[1]/Byline [1]','varchar(200)') as AuthorName  
      , cast(C.ContentXML as xml).value('Content[1]/Deck[1]','varchar(200)') as Description  
      , cast(C.ContentXML as xml).value('Content[1]/BodyContent[1]','varchar(max)') as ArticleDetails  
      , C.DateCreated as POSTING_DATETIME
from cmspage(nolock) P 
   join cmspagecontent(nolock)  PC on P.pageid = PC.pageid  
   join cmsContent(nolock) C on PC.contentid = C.contentid  
   join cmsContentType(nolock) CT on C.ContentTypeId = CT.ContentTypeId  
      where  C.DateCreated > getdate() - @NumberOfDays --100  
        AND    P.pagetemplateid in  (  
          select value from dbo.fnParseDelimString(@PageTemplateIds, ',')  
         --15252, --Article  
        --16543 -- Article - Infogram  
         )   
        and    PC.pagetemplatelocationid in  (  
          select value from dbo.fnParseDelimString(@PageTemplateLocationIds, ',')  
          --17163,  
           --15250  
           )   
        and    CT.contenttypeid in (select value from     dbo.fnParseDelimString(@ContentTypeIds, ','))--(6)   
        and    P.isactive = 1  
        and    P.HasBeenPublished = 1  
        and    P.IsRedirect = 0   
        --and  
            --C.DateCreated > getdate() - @NumberOfDays --100  
        and  
            P.pagesourceid in (select value from dbo.fnParseDelimString(@PageSourceIds,      ','))--(16,1896)  

      END
```

Comment: You could try to "prime" SQL server by first doing just a `TOP 1` select for the query so that it can formulate an effective execution plan, and then follow that with the full select. Also it might help to avoid using scalar functions and instead bring that logic into the sproc; the optimizer has a harder time optimizing scalars.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "slower". Is it a second slower, one minute, ten minutes?

Comment: During the first RUN it took 16 Sec. Second RUN it is almost instantaneous.

Comment: HAve you considered that correlated subqueries are almost alawys the slowest way to do something? They generally make the query need to run row-by-agonizing-row. They are only rarely actually needed and can be replaced by joins, exists or CTEs. TAble values functions may be slow as well and you need to read up on sargability to make sure your queries can use the indexes you have available.

Answer (score 2):

When SQL runs a query the first time, it compiles the query and creates a query plan for subsequent executions.  Thus the initial delay is SQL trying to figure out what logic to use based on schema, indexes, and statistics to most effectively find data.

The query you have there is not particularly crazy, but with all of those subselects I can see why it may take a bit for the server to determine the correct plan. Consider breaking the one-giant-query into a few staged ones and build simple tables to join for the final result.

More on query plans - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_plan

This may also be problematic, calculate this value before adding it to the where clause. Otherwise, SQL may calculate GETDATE() for every row comparison, causing additional slowness. Similarly, the function call may try to parse the values for each row (then again it may just be what is causing the compilation to take so long).

```
getdate() - @NumberOfDays
fnParseDelimString
```